# How to export ambient occlusion shadows only from Arnold Maya rendering to do multi layers composites

Tags: lighting, rendering, maya

I cannot find a way in Maya 2019 to create a rendering pass that only contains ambient occlusion generated shadows. I can do that with aiShadowMatte producing an expected alpha channel containing the shadows only but not with ambient occlusion shader aiAmbientOcclusion.